# Listbox looks different in xaml viewer than in the program window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, label

I'm working on a WPF Application, and i encountered the following problem,
ignored it until now though.

I want to display a Listbox and a Label on top of it.
For that I have the following XAML code:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="Packs" Margin="60, 65, 60, 0"/>
        <ListBox Grid.Column="1"  Height="200" Width="150"/>
    </Grid>
```

This gives the following output in the design window
[image: XAML Editor view]

You can ignore the buttons on the left.
As you can see the Label is right on top of the Listbox.

Now when I open my program, the window makes it seem like the Listbox is on top
of the Label.

[image: The program view]

I tried a lot rearranging the XAML-Code to display it differently, but this problem stay the same, and although I could bypass it by using values that are simply too big for the designer, it still bugs me that I can't find a solution.

Also please keep in mind that my program will not be resizeable, so dont worry about that.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: First, your first screenshot makes it really hard to see the Label. Second: why not put the label and the listbox in a stackpanel?

Comment: @greenjaed Hi, thanks for your reply. Is there a way to find out though why this resizes so weirdly?

Comment: It's impossible to say just from the code you posted; Copying and pasting just that doesn't produce the same behavior you're observing. Obviously from your screenshot, your have more to the layout than just a grid with three columns. You need to post a [minimal, reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put Label and ListBox in another Panel (StackPanel) and align that Panel in outer Grid:

```
<Grid> 
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" 
                Width="150" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Label Content="Packs"/>
        <ListBox Height="200"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

this way both elements will be in the center of middle column even if window is resized.